# Storing the data in array using ng-model

Tags: angularjs, html

I want to store the data in an array using the ng-model. I have an controller as RegisterController in which i inject `$scope` with ng-model name as user i.e. `$scope.user={}`.Here i am reading the data from form input element and submitting the data that has `ng-model="user.name"` and now i want to store that name or the multiple values in that user object.

```
<form class="well" align="center">
  <input ng-model="user.name" name="name"  type="text"><br/>
  <input ng-model="user.name" name="mobile"  type="text"><br/>
  <input ng-model="user.name" name="mail"  type="mail"><br/>
  <input ng-model="user.name" type="password" name="otp"><br/><br/>

  <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
  <a href="#/login">Login</a><br><br>
</form>
```

and the controller is

```
app.controller("RegisterController",function($scope){

  $scope.user={};
})
```

Now let me know to store the data in the user that as array with example

Comment: Suggest you show some minimal illustrative code, rather than explaining in words. It's not clear what you want the outcome to be and what array you are talking about

Comment: Yes here is the code

Comment: Did you reference to your controller `RegisterController` inside of your html? Currently I'm missing that, so it would never be able to work (unless you did it somewhere else).

Comment: As suggested below, bind each field to a different property of the `user` object, i.e. `ng-model="user.mail"` for mail). Still not sure what array you are talking about, since there is no array anywhere in your code.

Comment: here my array will be as $scope.user=[{}];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys it was very simple and now i get. In HTML it should be like this,

```
<div ng-controller="RegisterController">
<form class="well" align="center">
<input ng-model="user.name" name="name"  type="text"><br/>
<input ng-model="user.mobile name="mobile"  type="text"><br/>
<input ng-model="user.mail" name="mail"  type="mail"><br/>
<input ng-model="user.password" type="password" name="otp"><br/><br/>
<button type="button" ng-click="signup(user)">Sign Up</button>
<a href="#/login">Login</a><br><br>
</form>
</div>
```

Now In Register Controller, i need just, an array as follows:

```
app.controller("RegisterController",function($scope){
$scope.regruser=[];
$scope.signup=function(user){
$scope.regruser.push(user);
}
})
```

Now you can get $scope.regruser where you needed. as it having all registered user.

Answer (score 2):

I think your doing a small mistake. Instead of sending the same ng-model="user.name" send is as,

```
<form class="well" align="center">
<input ng-model="user.name" name="name"  type="text"><br/>
<input ng-model="user.mobile name="mobile"  type="text"><br/>
<input ng-model="user.mail" name="mail"  type="mail"><br/>
<input ng-model="user.password" type="password" name="otp"><br/><br/>

<button type="button">Sign Up</button>
<a href="#/login">Login</a><br><br>
</form>
```

And you have to send that ng-model to the function as in button

```
 <button type="button" ng-click="signup(user)">SignUp</button>
```

now you can able to get what you want

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @ANK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any benefit of storing the user model in an array. Instead extend the user model with properties name, mobileNumber, email, password

```
$.scope.user = {
   name: '',
   mobileNumber: '',
   email: ''
   password: ''
}
```

And in your html bind model properties to their corresponding input fields like

```
<input class="form-group" name="mobile"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" ng-model="user.name.mobileNumber"/>
```

And if you still need to have an array then parse the $scope.user model and extract values to array in angular controller.

Comment: Thats only my requirement. I want everything in an array or in JSON

Comment: "in `an array` or in `object notation`" what is that mean?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML PART**

```
<form class="well" align="center">
    <input class="form-group" name="name"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" ng-model="user.name"><br/>
    <input class="form-group" name="mobile"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" ng-model="user.mobile"><br/>
    <input class="form-group" name="mail"  type="mail" placeholder="Enter mail id" ng-model="user.mail"><br/>
    <input class="form.group" type="password"  name="otp" placeholder="Enter Password" ng-model="user.password"><br/><br/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" ng-click="signUp()">Sign Up</button>
<a href="#/login">Login</a><br><br>
</form>
```

**Code For Controller :**

```
$scope.user = {
   name: '',
   mobile: '',
   mail: '',
   password: ''
};
```

This answer is a correction to Andrejs Abrickis answer as well. Because:

1. **he misses comma after email**
2. **he misses  semi-colon after "}"**
3. **Adds an extra dot in between $ & scope**

Thanks You... Hope It Helps You all.. :)